# Javascript Chainable Closure

Tags: javascript, closures, chainable

Inspired by [If Hemingway Wrote Javascript](https://www.nostarch.com/hemingwayjs), I'm trying to write a chainable function closure with a private local variable.

The intended behavior is:

```
> chainableCounter()
0
> chainableCounter(1)(2)()
3
```

Here's my code:

```
function chainableCounter(n) {
    var acc = 0;

    var fn = function (x) {
        if (x === undefined) {
            return acc;
        } else {
            acc = acc + x;
            return fn;
        }
    };

    fn(n);
}
```

When I try to run this in the node REPL, this is what I get:

```
> chainableCounter()
undefined
> chainableCounter(1)
undefined
> chainableCounter(1)()
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

That `chainableCounter(1)` returns `undefined` instead of a function object seems to indicates that we're never hitting the line `return fn;`. But more than that, why does `chainableCounter()` also returning `undefined` when it should return `0`? What am I missing?

Comment: You want the function to return a function. Try changing the last line from `fn(n);` to `return fn;`.

Comment: @jordan, fn returns itself when invoked and he wants it called with the arg to chainableCounter. But the return part is right.

Comment: You need `chainableCounter` to return a function.

Comment: @Jordan fn, when invoked with an argument, returns a function. So we're OK there.

Comment: Right. I see that now. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fn(n)` returns to the point of the call. Your actual function `chainableCounter` doesn't return anything, it doesn't have a return statement.

You can just add it before calling `fn`, like this:

```
return fn(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be

`return fn(n);`

Because JavaScript needs an explicit return statement.